# how to set two different pin colors when populating mapview

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am parsing two json feeds. The first json feed parses pharmacies of a particular region and populates the mapview, the second feed parses a list of burger shops present in that region and populates the mapview. What I want is to set the pins representing the first feed in red color and the second feed in green color. I am a noob, could you help me out? Below is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"Map";
    [self secondMap];
    [self firstMap];
}

-(void)secondMap
{
     jsonurl1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPharmacyJson"];
     NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonurl1 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
     connection1=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self] autorelease];

     self.jsonData1=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl1];

     self.jsonArray1 = [self.jsonData1 objectFromJSONString]; 
     NSLog(@"blah:%@",jsonArray1);
     items= [self.jsonArray1 objectForKey:@"pharmacies"];
     NSDictionary *bam=[items valueForKey:@"location"];

     for (NSDictionary *item in bam)
     {
         latitude=[[item valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
         longitude=[[item valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

         NSLog(@"String3:%f",latitude);
         NSLog(@"String4:%f",longitude);
         Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
         home.name = [item valueForKey:@"Name"];
         // home.description=[item valueForKey:@"description"];
         home.latitude = latitude;
         home.longitude = longitude; 

         PlaceMark *from = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:home] autorelease];                
         [mapView addAnnotation:from];

         NSLog(@"the latitude:%f",latitude);
         NSLog(@"the latitude:%f",longitude);
         [self centerMap];
     }
}

-(void)firstMap
{
    jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/WhereIam?longitude=18.105469&latitude=59.304786&distance=100"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connection1=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

    //NSLog(@"jsonurl:%@",jsonurl);
    self.jsonData=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];

    self.jsonArray = [self.jsonData objectFromJSONString]; 
    NSLog(@"blah:%@",jsonArray);
    items = [self.jsonArray objectForKey:@"parks"];

    story = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    media1 = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    url=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    descriptiondesc=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
    for (NSDictionary *item in items )
    {
        latitude=[[item valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
        longitude=[[item valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

        NSLog(@"String1:%f",latitude);
        NSLog(@"String2:%f",longitude);
        Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        home.name = [item valueForKey:@"Name"];
        //  home.description=[item valueForKey:@"description"];
        home.latitude = latitude;
        home.longitude = longitude; 

        PlaceMark *from = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:home] autorelease];             
        [mapView addAnnotation:from];

        NSLog(@"the latitude:%f",latitude);
        NSLog(@"the latitude:%f",longitude);
        [self centerMap];
    }
}

-(void) centerMap
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.1;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.1;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    location.latitude=latitude;
    location.longitude=longitude;
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id       <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5); 

    UIButton *detailButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    //NSInteger annotationValue=[self.annotations indexOfObject:annotation];

    [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView)        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Don't set the mapType and showsUserLocation in viewForAnnotation which is called for each annotation.  Those properties apply to the whole map and are more appropriate to set in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you've created a `PlaceMark` class that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. So, what you could do is add a property to it that identifies whether it's a pharmacy or a burger shop, or simply sets its colour. Then, when you create it, make sure you set that property:

```
PlaceMark *from = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:home] autorelease];
from.colorName = @"red";
[mapView addAnnotation:from];
```

Then, in your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, you need to grab this out of the annotation you get passed.

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id       <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
    PlaceMark *placeMark = (PlaceMark*) annotation;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    if( [placeMark.colorName isEqualToString:@"red"] ) {
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    } else {
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }

    ...
 }
```

Comment: if i m to use from.colorName, i m getting error.should i have a use an ivar "colorName" in my PlaceMark?

Comment: i synthesized an NSString variable in the class PlaceMark and tried the above module you have given .i was able to differentiate the pincolor  for two different url's.when the first three pins get loaded .i m getting a shadow and my app is getting crashed ...the NSLog looks something like dis...[MKUserLocation colorName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc270...cud u help me out

Comment: Yes, the assumption is that you add an NSString ivar and @property to your PlaceMark called colorName. The error you're getting sounds like it doesn't have the @property/@synthesize added. Is it in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` when you do `placeMark.colorName isEqualToString`?

Comment: Regarding the unrecognized selector error, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4324612/467105).

Comment: thanks for your effort.i was able to figure out.i tried setting ivar in placemark but the app was getting crashed.so i set the NSSTring annotaiton as red an was able to make it work.cud u help me add an image instead of pins in mapview

Comment: Instead of creating an `MKPinAnnotationView`, try just creating a `UIImageView`.